# Are characteristic subgroups "unique" within the containing group?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

A *normal* subgroup is invariant through all *inner* automorphisms of the original group.

A *characteristic* subgroup is invariant through *all* automorphisms, period (inner or outer) of the original group.

An example of a normal but non-characteristic subgroup can be found in the multiplicative Quaternion group $Q$: The subgroup $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$ is normal, but not characteristic. By defining a "re-labelling" automorphism of $Q$ that swaps $i$ with $j$ (and $-i$ with $-j$, of course) we see that is obviously isomorphic to $\{1, -1, j, -j\}$, even though conjugation by no element of the group can achieve this mapping (i.e., it is an *outer* automorphism).

**Is this always the case?** In other words, which one of the following is true?

A) If a group $G$ contains a characteristic subgroup $H$, it can not contain any other subgroup different but isomorphic to $H$ ("only one copy").

B) A group $G$ *might* contain several different subgroups $H, H', H''...$, all isomorphic to each other, but still lack any automorphisms (inner or outer) that map the H between themselves.

It seems to me that the "re-labelling" used to generate the necessary outer automorphism in the Quaternion example (and thus prove the group non-characteristic) should always be achievable, but I am not confident of this.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone for the feedback. Now I see how short-sighted my question is: A group $G$ can potentially have many subgroups isomorphic to each other (e.g., several "copies" of $C_2$), perhaps *some* of them characteristic, without said isomorphisms necessarily extending to an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: There is no reasonable hope for the first statement to be true and it isn't.

Comment: So, a group can contain several different copies of a characteristic subgroup?

Comment: There is a non abelian group of order 3^3 with a characteristic subgroups of order 3, the derived subgroup, and all elements of order 3 —so that it has plenty of subgroups of order 3.

Comment: You should install GAP and play with it.

Answer (score 2):

A group can have 2 (or more) isomorphic subgroups, which are both characteristic and what is required is basically that you have 2 (or more) isomorphic subgroups that 'sit uniquely' in the lattice of subgroups. To give an explicit example. Have a look at this subgroup lattice for the semi-direct product $C_4 \rtimes C_4$. All of the ordered pairs are GAP ids for the groups in question.
[image]
The order 2 groups are identified as $(2,1)$. Notice how they each sit uniquely in the overall lattice (each is a member of a different number of order 4 subgroups!)

Comment: Since the image looks hand-constructed, do you know about the GAP command `DotFileLatticeSubgroups`?

Comment: I am familiar, but I found the results not very elegant to look at. For small enough groups, like this one, writing a short graphviz file gives a very nice picture, and I had already done this for many small groups for my own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dihedral group of order 8. Its center has order 2 and is characteristic, but it also contains other subgroups of order 2. There are plenty of other examples.

Comment: No, that is not the question: it only deals with *characteristic* subgroups.

Comment: Perhaps I worded my question poorly. The center is certainly characteristic, but this other order-2 subgroups arent, right? Still isomorphic I guess ($C_2$)

Comment: Well, reading A, you might think so, but not reading B. The problem is that A and B don't cover all the possible cases...

Comment: In other words, the situation I described definitely satisfies B.

Comment: In any case, you can also find examples of distinct isomorphic characteristic subgroups. The non-trivial semi-direct product of two cyclic groups of order $4$ has three subgroups of order $2$, and they are all characteristic.

Comment: Thank you both. It seems the example landscape is much richer in possibilities than I considered.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that I implicitly assumed that all subgroups $H, H', H''...$ in B) are characteristic is cause for confusion?